# Displaying PDF in vaadin

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin

I want to display PDF in my UI and got the following error:

```
May 25, 2012 11:29:11 AM com.vaadin.Application terminalError
SEVERE: Terminal error:
com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException
Cause: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: eu.livotov.tpt.gui.vdv.core.SinglePageDocumentRenderer.generateCell(Lcom/vaadin/ui/Table;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:532)
at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:164)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.fireEvent(AbstractComponent.java:1219)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:550)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button.changeVariables(Button.java:217)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.changeVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1445)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariableBurst(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1393)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1312)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:763)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(CommunicationManager.java:296)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:501)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:478)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:517)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:937)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:871)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:346)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:589)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1065)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:823)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:411)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:531)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:529)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: eu.livotov.tpt.gui.vdv.core.SinglePageDocumentRenderer.generateCell(Lcom/vaadin/ui/Table;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at com.vaadin.ui.Table.getVisibleCellsNoCache(Table.java:1691)
at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRenderedCells(Table.java:1479)
at com.vaadin.ui.Table.attach(Table.java:3341)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.attach(AbstractComponentContainer.java:97)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.attach(AbstractComponentContainer.java:97)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.attach(AbstractComponentContainer.java:97)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.attach(AbstractComponentContainer.java:97)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.setParent(AbstractComponent.java:560)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.addComponent(AbstractComponentContainer.java:211)
at com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet.addTab(TabSheet.java:294)
at com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet.addTab(TabSheet.java:332)
at com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet.addTab(TabSheet.java:311)
at com.complete.raspberry.webui.FileAdminView$SearchFormLayout$2.buttonClick(FileAdminView.java:166)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:512)
... 32 more
```

My code is like this:

```
Button advanceSearchButton = new Button("Advance Search",
   new Button.ClickListener() {
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

     DocumentViewer viewer = new DocumentViewer();
     viewer.loadDocument ( new PdfDocument ( new java.io.File ( "C:/handbook.pdf" ) ) );
     System.out.println("Pages pdf : " + viewer.getPagesCount());                           
     VerticalLayout myTabCoursPDF = new VerticalLayout();
     myTabCoursPDF.addComponent(viewer);  
     tabsheet.addTab(myTabCoursPDF);
```

I've also included the following JARs in my project:

- icepdf-core.jar
- icepdf-pro.jar
- icepdf-pro-intl.jar
- tpt-core.jar

Now what is the problem in my code... Can anyone plzz help me..

Comment: can you get more of the stack trace?

Comment: what do you mean by stack trace here?

Comment: yup sorry i've got more of the stack trace but didn't show the full stack trace here..

Comment: It throws exception when I try to add it in the tabsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the stack trace you posted, the method "generateCell" is not implemented in the class "eu.livotov.tpt.gui.vdv.core.SinglePageDocumentRenderer". This is being called when you add the new tab. According [to this thread](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/1436559), the TPT library may not be appropriate for use with Vaadin.

The click listener itself looks okay.

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: eu.livotov.tpt.gui.vdv.core.SinglePageDocumentRenderer.generateCell(Lcom/vaadin/ui/Table;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at com.vaadin.ui.Table.getVisibleCellsNoCache(Table.java:1691)
at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRenderedCells(Table.java:1479)
at com.vaadin.ui.Table.attach(Table.java:3341)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.attach(AbstractComponentContainer.java:97)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.attach(AbstractComponentContainer.java:97)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.attach(AbstractComponentContainer.java:97)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.attach(AbstractComponentContainer.java:97)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.setParent(AbstractComponent.java:560)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.addComponent(AbstractComponentContainer.java:211)
at com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet.addTab(TabSheet.java:294)
```

Comment: so now how can i use this DocumentViewer because i've to show my PDF to the client as an image so client can't print it..